# Excel VBA convert values of a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns from A1 to B10 in Sheet1. each cells in these columns have the strings "a" or "b" or "c"

```
     A    B
1    a    a
2    a    b
3    b    c
4    b    b
5    a    a
6    c    b
7    a    a
8    a    c
9    b    a
10   a    b
```

I want to convert every cell that has a value "a" to the integer "12", "b" to the integer "14" and "c" to the integer "16" using VBA. and show the results in Sheet2 in corresponding cells.

```
     A   B
1   12   12
2   12   14  
3   14   16
4   14   14
5   12   12
6   16   14
7   12   12
8   12   16
9   14   12
10  12   14
```

I have this very incomplete codes:

```
Sub getConvert()

For Each original In Range("A1 , B10")
 Select Case original
   Case "a"
    CorrectedText = Replace(original, "a", "12")
   Case "b"
    CorrectedText = Replace(original, "b", "14")
   Case Else
    CorrectedText = Replace(original, "c", "16")
 End Select
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you get ? or What is not working ? I suspect you should use `Select Case original.value` or `original.textValue` (as `original` is a range object, not text.

Comment: and I don't know how to paste result into another Sheet in corresponding cells?

Comment: Prepend original with `sheets(2)` should be enough. But you may have to use `sheets(2). Original.range.value =` (untested and unsure from memory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access each cell, read its value then overwrite in your loop:

```
Dim original As Range, destination As Worksheet

Set destination = Sheets("Sheet2")

For Each original In Range("A1:B10")
    Select Case original.Value
        Case "a": destination.Range(original.Address).Value = "12"
        Case "b": destination.Range(original.Address).Value = "14"
        Case "c": destination.Range(original.Address).Value = "16"
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: and I don't know how to paste result into another Sheet in corresponding cells?